# Pandas multiple dataset plot error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have multiple datasets that I need to be plotted on the same axes.
Just an example of the datasets are:
Dataset 01 as two separate lists:

```
Waves          Values
340            520
341            532
342            536
.              .
.              .
2500           720
```

Dataset 02 as a dataframe df:

```
Wavelength      Data
320             560
350             572
.               .
.               .
2650            780
```

My attempt at the plot is as follows:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax = plt.plot(x = Waves , y = Values)   # list names
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Wavelength', y='Data')
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT GRAPH]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redefine the axes `ax`, created in the first line, to be a list of lines via `ax=plt.plot(..)`. Remove this redefinition.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax.plot(Waves, Values)
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Wavelength', y='Data')
plt.show()
```

Comment: this did get rid of the error, but it doesn't plot the (x= Waves, y = Values) at all....just the df.plot (only the blue line plot in my sample output pic)

Comment: Sorry, I just copied that from your code without testing as there is no [mcve]. The problem is that matplotlib plot's `x` and `y` argument are no named arguments.